# evaluating size of the array

Tags: c, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

sample code written in `c`

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[]="Visual C++";
    char b[] = "Visual\C++";
    printf("%d, %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b));
    printf("%d, %d", sizeof(*a), sizeof(*b));
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

**`11,10`**

**`1,1`**

1.) Why **`sizeof(a)`** shows `11`, although, it has only `10` characters.

2.) Why **`sizeof(a)`** and **`sizeof(b)`** showing different output, although, they have same number of characters.

Comment: Don't forget the null character... And the backlash `\\` is an escape character.

Comment: which means.. if we don't know the size of the array, and we have to iterate whole elements of the array. so on that case, will have to move till **`(sizeof(a)-2)`** isn't ??

Comment: `sizeof(a)` will give you the size of the array. (and also the length of the array for type `char`). `strlen(a)` will give you the number of characters before the first null character.

Comment: `'\C'` is undefined behavior, and you should use a more appropriate conversion specifier for the type `size_t`: `%u` (better with a cast) in C89, `%zu` from C99.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is a `null` (`\0`) at the end of the string and `\C` is interpreted as a single character.

If you want the backslash to show in a C string you must escape it using another backslash.

```
char b[] = "Visual\C++";  \\ 10 characters including the null terminator
char b[] = "Visual\\C++"; \\ 11 characters including the null terminator
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - becuase the string has a 00 byte (aka null terminator) on it thats included in the sizeof

2 *a is the first character in the string - size of 1 char is 1

Answer (score 0):

`a` contains 10 characters, *plus the terminating null (`'\0'`) character*; hence the size is 11.

And `a` and `b` do not contain the same number of characters. In `b`, the `\C` part is considered an escape sequence, and is counted as one character. If you want the `\` to appear, use `"Visual\\C++"`.

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1:**

"Visual C++" length = 11 /* including null character */

"Visual\C++" length = 10 /* including null character and '\C' is interpreted as one character.

**Point 2:**

`*a` means you are accessing the first character.

`*a` <=> `a[0]` both are same.

`a[0]` is 'V' in your case whose length is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it from a character stand point:

```
char a[]="Visual C++";

printf("length = %d\n", strlen(a));
for(int i = 0; i<strlen(a); i++)
    printf("a[%d] = %c (ASCII %d)", i, a[i], a[i]);
```

With code like this, you'll get

```
length = 11
a[0] = V (86)
a[1] = i (105)
a[2] = s (115)
a[3] = u (117)
a[4] = a (97)
a[5] = l (108)
a[6] =   (32)
a[7] = C (67)
a[8] = + (43)
a[9] = + (43)
a[10] =  (0)
```

Checking those values against an [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see why it shows 11 (the `NULL` terminator)

```
char b[] = "Visual\C++";
```

Your second string has an escape char in it `\`, there's lots of [lists of them](http://www.wilsonmar.com/1eschars.htm), but it basically tells the compiler to ignore the next character because it's not to be printed, but something special. Just like the newline character: `'\n'`

---

Based on your comments on the original post, I think I need to clarify two extra things:

**Extra Note 1:**
A special char, such as newline `'\n'` or null terminator `'\0'` only takes 1 extra byte of space.

**Extra Note 2:**
`sizeof(a)` will give you the size (number of characters) of your array because it's full of characters which only take 1 byte each. When you're using this on other types that take up more space you need to do one more step:

```
int arr[4] = {0};
int size_of_arr = sizeof(arr/sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the linux kernel that is the macro:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))
```